# Why do "svn" commands block in gnome-terminal for couple of minutes (But Guake Terminal works instantly)?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, svn, guake

I am facing a strange problem where svn commands block for a couple of minutes if I use gnome-terminal. So does UXTerm and Terminator. But strangely Guake Terminal works fine.

I ran the following command both in gnome-terminal and Guake Terminal:

```
strace -r -o strace.outfile svn ls svn://192.168.1.10
```

I have pasted the output for gnome-terminal here: http://pastebin.com/57sp8vxK. As you can see in case of gnome-terminal the poll waits for 25 seconds at line-no 40. I've shown only the first wait. It happens multiple times for a total of 145 seconds. It does not wait like that in the Guake terminal.

Any idea? What they are waiting for and why it happens only in gnome-terminal?

My System Information:

```
> cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS \n \l
> uname -a
Linux sabya-ubuntu 3.2.0-49-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 18 17:39:32 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Somewhere within the "content removed for brevity" is where fd 4 was created, and polling fd 4 is where the problem happens. It should be really useful to know what descriptor 4 is for. Be careful hiding information that you think are irrelevant to a problem you're facing. You are looking for help because you don't understand why a problem is happening, meaning that you're a poor judge of what information is irrelevant.

Comment: I think you missed the first line. It is where FD 4 is being created using `eventfd2(0, O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC) = 4` call. Isn't it? I have removed the data being sent and received on the socket. Because it might contain the credentials being send.